# Trying to test a GraphQLError using expect().toThrow

Tags: typescript, jestjs, graphql, ts-jest

I have a `GraphQLError` like so:

```
export const notFoundError = (msg: string): GraphQLError => {
    return new GraphQLError(msg, {
        extensions: { code: "NOT_FOUND" }
    });
};
```

and let's say a function that throws this error

```
export function test() {
    throw notFoundError("no item found")
}
```

How do I test this is jest? something like:

```
expect(() => {
test();
}).toThrow((error: GraphQLError) => {
    // expect statements to test the message and code
})
```

I tried this, however, I get an error saying

```
expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Expected constructor name is an empty string
    Received constructor: GraphQLError

    Received message: "no item found"

          2 |
          3 | export const notFoundError = (msg: string): GraphQLError => {
        > 4 |     return new GraphQLError(msg, {
            |            ^
          5 |         extensions: { code: "NOT_FOUND" }
          6 |     });
          7 | };
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that the argument could be a function receiving the error - that's not one of the four [documented](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror) options.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean @jonrsharpe, it is this method [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror)

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing I linked to. _"You can provide an optional argument to test that a specific error is thrown"_ but none of the four options for that argument matches what you've tried to write here (which is more like a [`toSatisfy`](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/matchers/tosatisfy) predicate).

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation at https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

Should be something like:

```
test('test notFoundError', () => {
  const notFoundError = (msg: string): GraphQLError => {
    throw new GraphQLError(msg, {
      extensions: { code: "NOT_FOUND" }
    });
  };

  expect(() => notFoundError("no item found")).toThrow(new GraphQLError("no item found", {
    extensions: { code: "NOT_FOUND" }
  }));

});
```

note: looks like this only matches the message

Comment: I have looked at documentation. Have you tried this? This seemingly does not do a deep equality for extensions. Let know if this actually works

Comment: im finding the same thing, looks like it only looks for match in the message not the object

Comment: want to say thanks, this saved me from implementing some faulty tests, i landed on setting two tests one to check error type and one to check the message

Comment: Indeed, it only matches the message. You can test this by changing `code: "NOT_FOUND"` in the `expect` to be anything, and the test will still succeed. Good call @ocShawn I learned something new today.